# Mupx not working. Fails verifying deployment.

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, meteor-up

I am trying to deploy my meteor app with mupx. Everything works with `mupx setup` and `mupx deploy` until it tries to verify, then I get this error:

```
[wyno.io] x Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
unction._.each._.forEach (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
=> Starting meteor app on port:80

/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:283
}).run();
   ^
Error: $ROOT_URL, if specified, must be an URL
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Meteor.absoluteUrl.options (packages/meteor/url_server.js:8:1)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1130:4
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1272:3
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:137:5

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I run `mupx logs` I get the error

```
[wyno.io] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[wyno.io] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[wyno.io] => Starting meteor app on port:80
[wyno.io] 
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:283
[wyno.io] }).run();
   ^
[wyno.io] Error: $ROOT_URL, if specified, must be an URL
    at Error (<anonymous>)
[wyno.io]     at Meteor.absoluteUrl.options (packages/meteor/url_server.js:8:1)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1130:4
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1272:3
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
[wyno.io]     at Function._.each._.forEach (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

I'm very bad with server configuration and not sure where to go from here except a failing at searching for an answer online. I'm running a $20 a month Ubuntu 14.04 droplet from Digital Ocean.

Comment: looks like your `ROOT_URL` is not set right ;-) so far, quite obvious. Show your mup.json and maybe we'll be able to help.

Comment: Silly me... I didn't prefix my domain name with http:// in the "env"."ROOT_URL". Thank you for this answer as reading it prompted me to do that after days of struggling.